# Set Algebra problems

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I am practicing some set algebra problems for my midterms however for this problem I cannot seem to give like a logical explanation to part $a, b$. For instance for **a.** I can imagine that $A\subset D$ (maybe this is wrong), but I cannot give a mathematical explanation or having hard time writing one.

Can anyone give me some hints or how to solve this problem? It would really help me understand how to reason or understand set algebra better.

Comment: Well, $B\cap D \subset D$ so $A = B\cap D\subset D$ so $A \subset D$ is certainly true. But we also know that other then that elements of $A$ that $D$ contains no element of $B$.  So the elements of $D$ that aren't in $A$ are not in $B$ at all.  So $D\setminus A \subset B^c$.  But I'm not sure that second is what the text is going for as that's a comment about the relation ship between the three sets; not just $A$ and $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) it might help to draw a Venn diagram of $B\cap D=A$. You’ll have two overlapping circles, one for $B$ and one for $D$, and the lens-shaped region where they overlap must represent $A$. So what can you say about the relationship between $D$ and $A$? Not much, since you really haven’t much information, but you can definitely say that $A\subseteq D$. Or you can work from the definition of intersection: $B\cap D$ is the set of things that are in both $B$ and $D$, so if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$ and $x\in D$. In particular, every $x\in A$ is in $D$, so $A\subseteq D$. (You could also conclude that $A\subseteq B$, but you already knew that from the statement at the beginning of the question.)

A Venn diagram might also help you with (b). Since you know that $B\subseteq C$, you’ll have a circle for $B$ inside a circle for $C$. You’re told that $B\cup D=C$, so $D$ has to include everything in $C$ that $B$ does not include. In other words, we must have $D\supseteq C\setminus B$.

In (c) you need to combine the conclusions from the first two parts: describe a set $D$ (in terms of $A,B$, and $C$) that satisfies the requirement that $A\subseteq D$ and the requirement that $D\supseteq C\setminus B$. There’s only one such set that you can describe concretely; it’s the smallest one, the one that just barely meets these requirements.

Comment: this was very helpful thank you very much

Comment: @AuroraBorealis: You’re very welcome.